# log4j - rootLogger without appender gives warning

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have defined appenders for all the log files which I need. So, I thought there is no need for an appender for the rootLogger as there is nothing to log in rootLogger. So, I changed the line in log4j.properties from:

`log4j.rootLogger=debug,default`

to

`log4j.rootLogger=debug`

But I am getting the following warning on application startup.

`log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.`

So, is there any way to achieve the intention i.e. not to redirect rootLogger logs to any appenders without getting any error or warning?

Answer (score 1):

So are you saying you don't need a rootLogger at all? If that's the case, you should delete the `log4j.rootLogger=debug`

altogether. The log4j system is expecting you to add an appender to any declared log, so deleting the rootLogger should remove the problem.